# Day of the Year in Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with D_Number being the corresponding to the day number in the year.

```
Date       D_Number     Schedule
9/24/2015   267            3T
10/15/2015  288            2R
11/5/2015   309            PR
```

I have the following query.

```
$day_num=date("z")+1;

$query_Recordset2 = "SELECT * FROM b_schedule_dates WHERE      
b_schedule_dates.D_Number = $day_num";
```

Basically, if today was 10/15/2015 or day number 267, the schedule to be followed is 3T.

I have a second query that is looking for the schedule to echo.

```
$day= date('w');
$day_num=date("z")+1;
$sched=$row_Recordset2['Schedule'];
$d_number=$row_Recordset2['D_Number'];

if($day_num === $d_number){
    $s=$sched;

}else {
    $s="2R";
}

if (isset($s)) {
    $colname_Recordset1 = $s;
}

$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM b_schedule WHERE b_schedule.Schedule =%s"
```

What am I doing wrong? It does not seem to recognize the 1st query's $day_num. I just want it to follow the corresponding schedule if the date happens, with each date having its own distinct schedule. If not it just needs to follow schedule 2R. b_schedule just has different schedule with different start and end times based on the schedule.

```
Start     End      Schedule
8:00:00   9:30:00     3T
8:00:00   10:30:00    2R
8:00:00    2:30:00    PR
```

Comment: did you try putting quotes around your variable? you really should look at parameterizing your query

Comment: Did you have a paste error? Where is the rest of the `sprintf` call?

Comment: The `isset($s)` test is unnecessary. The `if/else` before that **always** sets `$s`.

Comment: Why are you doing two queries instead of joining the two queries?

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the value, since it's a string:

```
$query_Recordset1 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM b_schedule WHERE b_schedule.Schedule = '%s'", $s);
```

But you can combine the two queries with a join, and also make use of MySQL's date functions.

```
SELECT *
FROM b_schedule_dates AS d
JOIN b_schedule AS s ON s.Schedule = d.Schedule
WHERE d.D_Number = DAYOFYEAR(NOW());
```

Comment: Did not work. The page is pretty complicated. I am first following a schedule based on days of the week with Monday being 1 and Friday being 2. I then have an exception table with dates to overrule the day of the week schedule. That is why I have 2 separate queries, with query 2 dependent on query 1.

Comment: I don't want to join. I thought I could create a dependency on query 1 for query 2. If I wanted nothing else but to echo the schedule if today happens to be a d_number how would I do it?

Comment: You can add more to the join, this is just a simple example.

Comment: Anyway, the first part of my answer shows how to do that.

Comment: The quotes did not fix.

Comment: If the quotes didn't fix it, then the problem is with how you're setting `$s`.